# Can different varieties of modality be used with existential quantification?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, philosophy-of-logic, possible-worlds

[I'm wondering](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/33666/what-is-the-difference-between-%E2%88%83-existence-and-a-actuality?noredirect=1#comment80114_33666) if it makes sense to talk about worlds which aren't this one being real.

It *seems* like you can claim that something possibly exists.

Now I'm wondering, because it *seems* to amount to the above question, whether I can claim that **it is possible for something to exist, but it actually doesn't, and in some [other sense](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-varieties/) actually does**.

- Would any philosophy of logic mean that you cannot?

Comment: sorry if it's a bad question, i'm low on google confidence today

Comment: "does not actually physically exist, but actually does" -- do you mean to ask whether "actually physically" and "actually" are different?

Comment: @EliranH i guess so yes

Comment: Can you give an example? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/actualism/

Comment: @user4894 the cricket ball could physically have broken the window, it physically didn't, but actually did... i.e. is this forbidden in any philosophy of logic rather than metaphysics

Comment: i'm guessing that it makes no sense to say that something cannot be logically expressed without there being any extra logical concerns to motivate the rejection

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN Are you talking about possible worlds? In some other world I might be the Pope but in this world I'm not? I don't follow what you mean by it physically did but actually didn't. This is very unclear.

Comment: @user4894 any clearer now?

Comment: Consider law -- the ultimate source for things internally contradictory that still have to be interpreted.  I have a financial obligation under law (gay alimony) that is recorded contractually but forbidden in various juristictions (North Carolina) but for which I must account on my federal taxes.  So it exists, but it doesn't, and yet in another sense it does.

Comment: More to the point,some moral obligations may exist in a doxastic mode (I believe they are obligations, perhaps from my religion), and then may not exist in any way in an alethic mode (in physical reality they do not predict outcomes if no one enforces them per se), but then do exist in a deontological mode (in ethics, if they are just the religious version of something more universal).  All of those modes are actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about [possible worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possible_world), "**actual**" is used to refer to this world, i.e. the one we live in. Thus you can say "I could have been president, but actually I am not". In possible worlds words, "there is some possible world in which I am president, but not in this one."

In direct response to your question, keeping the terminology in mind, one can say: "there *actually* aren't any unicorns, but there could have been", thus using the existential quantifier with a modal operator. The sentence "there could have been unicorns" is formalized as follows:

> ◇∃xUnicorn(x)

Read "It is possible that there are unicorns".

This may sound odd, and indeed some have objected to introducing [quantification to modal logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#QuaModLog) (the logic that deals with possible worlds), most famously Quine.

---

It is of course important to be clear about what kind of possibility you are talking about. For example, some things are [**logically possible**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_possibility), but not physically possible. It is logically possible for me to jump 100 meters in the air, but it is physically impossible. **Physical possibility** is usually taken to be as in accordance with the laws of nature.

So, you may say that it is logically possible that there are unicorns, but physically impossible (say in case they have some property that is incompatible with the laws of nature). You have to specify the kind of possibility you are talking about to avoid equivocation.

Comment: sorry for editing the question

Comment: what about: "it is possible that there are unicorns, but unicorns are physically impossible"

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN edited my answer for that.

Comment: ok, looks like there's no issue with expressing this, thanks